# Transitions browser issue Css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have searched and I am unable to locate a solution. I have a section  with an id called **#games** and i have the following link setup.

```css
#games a {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
}

#games a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 5);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<section id="games">
    <a href="https://www.game.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-3 col-pad">
            <img src="http://kurld.com/images/wallpapers/games-pictures/games-pictures-10.jpg">
            <h3>My Game Title</h3>
            <dl class="clearfix">
                <dd>Gamename</dd>
                <dd>Stats</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

It works in Mozilla but it has like a buggy transition. and in chrome or explorer it does not work at all. I am also using foundation. I removed the foundation css but it had no affect.

Comment: You don't need to redefine the transition in the hover definition. Also, your opacity declaration and opacity filter don't agree (60% vs 5%). This will lead to inconsistent behaviour in different browsers.

Comment: But what is your exact goal here? What do you want to achieve with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:block` on `a` and it will work this is because the `a` tag is an inline element. and if you 'inspect element' on the 'a' element you will see that it doesn't wrap around the elements that are inside it .

let me know if this is what you were looking for

```css
#games a {
  display:block;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
}

#games a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 5);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<section id="games">
    <a href="https://www.game.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-3 col-pad">
            <img src="images/games/myimage.jpg">
            <h3>My Game Title</h3>
            <dl class="clearfix">
                <dd>Gamename</dd>
                <dd>Stats</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `transition` statement is missing the `fade` parameter - try:

```
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few issues following up from my comment on the original post.

First: anchors are inline elements by nature. You can't put block elements inside inline elements, so this is where the other answers come into play (make your anchor `inline-block` or `block`).

Second: You don't need to redefine your transition on hover unless you're changing the properties. `:hover` is a more specific selector, but it doesn't invalidate other styles on that element. You should also probably explicitly add a transition function to both tailor your application's behaviour to your needs and to make the style more readable.

Third: Opacity is [universally supported after IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity), so you don't really need the `filter`. This is especially true since you have a different opacity specified by the filter, which will result in inconsistent behaviour.

Fourth: Transitions are also [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). The only prefix you really need is `-webkit-`, and even that isn't really needed most of the time.

**Updated code**:

```css
#games a {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1.0;
    
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
            transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

#games a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<section id="games">
    <a href="https://www.game.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-3 col-pad">
            <!-- This image is dead anyway, so I'm commenting it out for now -->
            <!-- <img src="http://kurld.com/images/wallpapers/games-pictures/games-pictures-10.jpg"> -->
            <h3>My Game Title</h3>
            <dl class="clearfix">
                <dd>Gamename</dd>
                <dd>Stats</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` on `#game a`.

```css
#games a {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
    display:inline-block;
}

#games a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 5);
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;    
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<section id="games">
    <a href="https://www.game.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-3 col-pad">
            <img src="images/games/myimage.jpg">
            <h3>My Game Title</h3>
            <dl class="clearfix">
                <dd>Gamename</dd>
                <dd>Stats</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

Comment: DO NOT USE `inline-block` because if you will add another inline element after that `a`( a new sibling ) , like `a`, `span`, `img` they will all stay on one line. and i don't think that's what would the OP want. see here an example : https://jsfiddle.net/bcp5a4d5/

Comment: @MihaiT WE HAVE NO IDEA ;) what the OP wants - it may be that, it may be marshmallows. But you're absolutely correct about adding other inline elements and the effect.